# Can I find what was the most relevant field in multi_match query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

For example in this request:

```
GET /recipes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "pasta pesto",
      "fields": ["title", "description"]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way, for each result, to know which field between the title and the description got the best score ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, you will not get this information, but you can use the [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) which will explain the complete details on scoring and will help you to determine that in your data-set for a given query and search results, which added how much score and how the score was calculated.

Comment: My question was not about debugging purpose but for real use in my application. If I understand correctly, you confirm that this is impossible.

Comment: @Koala-Gentil, you can include this `explain` param in each of your search query and by parsing the output you will get to know, but yes out of the box there is no simple way to achieve it and including `explain` with every query and parsing huge output will be costly.